# Spark Out of memory exception in executors

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive, out-of-memory, parquet

My functionality is  reading hive 10 table in spark and join based on some keys creating a

Dataset = joining all tables.

then applying some business logic on top of the dataset to create another output of dataset

Dataset = apply buisness logic on Daaset

then store in output Dataset in another hive table . this is completely working

we split the functionality into two by reading the 10 hive table  apply the join  and  store the intermediate   Dataset in one hive table .

the read one hive table Dataset in apply business logic and store the outout of Datasetin final hive table which leads the out of memory exception in excutors at exit code 143 in yarn

Spark configuaration are all same in both process.

would this scenario make a difference in memory of spark.

tried increasing executors memory but no use

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing both spark.driver.memory, spark.executor.memory

Comment: I’m not using any collect in my process . I’m just using flat map in the data frame and store directly in executors